# How many CPUs are there in a dedicated m4.16xlarge instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm confused about the physical configurations I get from dedicated hosts. According to the instance type matrix, an `m4.16xlarge` instance is powered by (not sure how many) Intel Xeon E5-2686 v4 CPUs, so I imagine if I launch one of the dedicated instances, I'll get to use the entire E5-2686 CPUs, however many are there. Right?

But I'm confused now. The instance type matrix says that an `m4.16xlarge` instance has 64 vCPU's. But as according to Intel, an E5-2686 v4 has only 18 cores / 36 threads. What does this mean? Do they put two CPUs in an m4.16xlarge machine? Couldn't find any reference for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m4 are dual socket, see the table on this page (seems not updated to reflect the new size yet): https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/pricing/

So the host should have 36 physical cores, 72 threads of which 64 threads can be used for ec2 instances.

Comment: That table is very helpful. They're scattered around and hard to find.